# Subscribe on methods execution c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, system.reflection

I`m looking for help in a next question. Can i subscribe on method execution with reflection in c#? 
What i have - method in class marked with attribute.

```
[MYATTRIBUTE]
private void Func()
{}
```

What i need - the way when i can find this method by reflection, and track when it will executed.
Is it exist ? 
I`l try to find something, but nothing. Help please.
Maybe i can pass smth in attribute to make it work ?
I believe i can do it with Diagnostics, but still need some explanations.

Comment: Call a method on the first line of the Func method which notifies those who are intrested when it is executed?

Comment: Thnx, but i need to find the way how to do it, without changing existing code